# Most efficient way to code a large multi-step form in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, database, forms, controls, multi-step

I have a large multi-step form that will insert a record into a database.  I'm using ASP.NET and I know there are some pre-made controls you can use for this, but I'm not all that familiar with all of them.  The formview seems to be a good control, but I'm not sure if it could be used with multiple steps/pages...?  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [Wizard control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Alright... it's not a data control though, is there a data control that I can use with it?  Or should I not bother with a pre-made data control and try to hand-code that part?

Comment: I'd hand-code that part.  You could always use data grids, form views, etc inside the wizard pages.